# JQuery local variable will not reset

Tags: jquery

I have a local variable with a JQuery function. Every time I run the function, the variable retains data from the previous run.

I have tried :

```
delete myVar; 
myVar = undefined;
```

Both at the beginning of the function but the old data persists. What am I doing wrong ?

```
$.get("http://api.lmiforall.org.uk/api/v1/ashe/estimatePay",
{ soc: soc, coarse: "false", filters:"region:12"},
function(datani) {
nipay=undefined; // clear variable data
nipay = maxBy("year", datani.series).estpay ; // load data into variable
if(nipay) { //check that variable contains data
}
else {
    nipay="Not available"; // Message if no data
}
$("#graph-box1").html("<p><b>NI:</b> " + nipay + " GBP/week </p>") //    display the result

});
```

Comment: Show the function.

Comment: if you can show your code we might be able to find out the mistake

Comment: Can you do myVar =' ' or myVar =0 according to type of your data?

Comment: [Setting to `undefined` should do the trick..](https://jsfiddle.net/1kjwo67m/)

Comment: Thanks for replying. I have added the full code for the function.

Comment: your `maxBy` function must be returning the same value...

Answer (score 3):

Your variable is not declared in the scope of the function because you're missing a `var` declaration. In this case it's declared in the global scope and thus the value from the previous run is retained, because the variable is persisted on the global scope.

```
var nipay = maxBy("year", datani.series).estpay;
```

Comment: Thanks for this. OK I just tried it with var nipay but the old data persists if new data fails to load due to any error.